# expect sudo ssh login issue

Tags: bash, expect

i wrote an expect script to ssh remotely to multiple linux boxes and running this command chmod -R o-w /etc/
But i am getting an error expect: invalid option -- 'R'

Please find the script below

```
#!/bin/bash
username=$1
userpass=$2
rootpass=$3
cat server_list | while read host
do
expect -c "
set timeout 5
spawn ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -tq ${username}@${host} sudo su - root
expect "ssword" { send "${userpass}r" }
expect "ssword" { send "{rootpass}r" }
expect "#"
send "chmod -R o-w /etc"
expect "#" { send "exitr" }
expect eof"
done
```

i am running the script like this

./test1.sh test test@123 test@123

Kindly help

Comment: Your quoting is not consistent. Try to avoid using double quotes inside the expect command that is itself in double quotes. Not sure if this is the only issue here.

Answer (score 0):

Use  "--" flags in the send command which will force the next argument to be read as string.

```
send -- "chmod -R o-w /etc"
```

Read more in [Expect manpage](http://www.tcl.tk/man/expect5.31/expect.1.html)

Comment: hi ashish  please find the output  expect: invalid option -- 'R'  issue is chmod is  a linux command. seems like expect is trying to run it as an expect command